# Projection of a uniform distribution on a sphere

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is a random vector distributed uniformly on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What is the probability density function of $X_1$?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019286/if-u-is-uniformly-distributed-on-s2-then-its-first-component-is-uniforml/1019854#1019854

Comment: This question was answered by Archimedes in about the third century BC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a uniform distribution.  See [this article](http://www.ams.org/notices/201210/rtx121001416p.pdf).  It is essentially a result in geometry proved by Archimedes.

From the linked article:

> > > **Proposition 1.** If $V$ is uniformly distirbuted on the interval $(-1,1)$ and if $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,2\pi)$ and independent of $V$, then
> > >       $$
> > > (V,\sqrt{1-V^2} \cos(\Theta),\sqrt{1-V^2}\sin(\Theta))
> > > $$
> > >       is uniformly distributed on the surface of the two-dimensional sphere of radius one.

Comment: PS: A corollary is that $\sqrt{1-V^2}\cos\Theta$ is also uniformly distributed.

Comment: PS: A corollary is that $\sqrt{1-V^2}\sin(\Theta)$ is also uniformly distributed.

Comment: Does this generalize in some way to higher dimensions? E.g., Can we write the uniform distribution over the 4-d sphere as the product of [-1,1] and a uniform point on a 3-d sphere? What about as a product of two uniform points on circles?