# If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $S^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, what's the distribution of its orthogonal projection onto any vector?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

Let $U \in S^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ follow a uniform distribution on a sphere. Let $v \in  \mathbb{R}^d.$ Then is the orthogonal projection $U^{T}v=\langle U,v \rangle$ uniformly distributed, and if yes/no, how do I go about proving it? This is motivated by [this relevant question for uniform distributions on 2D spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019286/if-u-is-uniformly-distributed-on-s2-then-its-first-component-is-uniforml). If it's wrong, could you give a counterexample?

If it's ***not*** uniformly distributed, how can we find the PDF of $U^{T}v=\langle U,v \rangle?$

Comment: $U$ is a vector right? So $Uv$ is what? A real number given by the euclidean product?

Comment: @Stockfish Ah sorry, yes $U$ is a vector it's indeed $U^{T}v$, the scalar product.

Comment: Simpler question : taking $v = e_1 = (1,0,...,0)$, we have $U^Tv = U_1$. Now, the question is : if $U$ is uniformly distributed on the $d-1$ sphere, is $U_1$ uniformly distributed? Think about this one.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $d=2$ and $v$ has unit-length. Then  $U^Tv= \cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $U$ and $v$. Clearly $\theta$ is uniformly distributed in $[-\pi,\pi]$, but you can check that $\cos \theta$ is not uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @JanBohr Thanks for your comment - I need to think; but it seems this question says that the projection is uniformly distributed if I'm not mistaken? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019286/if-u-is-uniformly-distributed-on-s2-then-its-first-component-is-uniforml?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон It seems the answer is yes from this question asked before? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647552/projections-of-uniformly-distributed-mathbbr3-unit-vector-have-uniform-dis

Comment: @LearningMath That is for $d=3$, right?

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Thanks again! Yes it is. So for $d=2, d\ge 4,$ it's no longer true...? And if it's not the uniform distribution, can we find the general PDF for $U^{T}v?$

Comment: I think it can be done in general, but I can't do it, I'm stuck myself!  (Of course, for $d=2$, Bohr told you it is the distribution induced by the random variable $\theta \to \cos \theta$, which is not uniform).

Comment: The square of your $\langle U,v\rangle$ has a "beta distribution" if $\|v\|=1$, as can be seen from the representation of $U=Z/\|Z\|$ where the coordinates of $Z$ are iid $N(0,1)$.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for your comment, could you please elaborate it a bit more, or write it as answer please?

Answer (score 4):

Let $v$ be a unit vector.
Since the orthogonal group acts transitively on the unit sphere, there exists a rotation matrix $R$ such that $Rv=e$, where $e=(1,0,\ldots,0)'$.

Now let $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_d)'$ be a vector of independent identically distributed $N(0,1)$ random variables.
The distribution of $Z$ is clearly rotationally invariant, and the normalized vector $U=Z/\|Z\|$ is uniformly distributed over the unit sphere, as is $R'U$. (See, eg, the answer by Henricus V. to this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585975/how-to-generate-random-points-on-a-sphere), and comments, and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444700/uniform-distribution-on-the-surface-of-unit-sphere), about this trick. It is a converse to [Maxwell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem).)
The quantity $\langle U, v\rangle=\langle U,Re\rangle=\langle R' U,e\rangle,$ so the distribution of  $\langle U, v\rangle$
is the same as that of $\langle U, e\rangle$.
So we may as well assume $v=e$ in working out the distribution of $T=\langle U,v\rangle$.

With this notation,  $T=\langle U,v\rangle=Z_1/\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d Z_i^2}$, and $T^2=Z_1^2/\sum_{i=1}^d T_i^2$.
The quantities $Z_i^2$ are iid [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Gamma,_exponential,_and_related_distributions) distributed: $Z_i^2\sim\Gamma(\frac 1 2,\frac 1 2)$ and $\sum_{i=2}^d Z_i^2\sim\Gamma(\frac{d-1}2,\frac 12)$ and [hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions)  $T^2$ has the $\operatorname{Beta}(\frac 1 2,\frac {d-1}2)$  distribution.
If we write $W=T^2$, the density function of $W$ is proportional to $w^{-\frac{1}2} (1-w)^{\frac{d-1}2-1}$ for $0<w<1$, and the density of $T$ is  proportional to $(1-t^2)^{(d-3)/2}$ for $-1<t<1$. Only if $d=3$ does the distribution of $T$ become uniform over its range.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To finish your line of arguments, I think we need to show that any uniform distribution $U$ on the sphere can be written as a ratio $U:= Z/||Z||, Z=(Z_1 \dots Z_d), Z_i \sim_{iid} \mathcal{N}(0,1).$ Is it obvious, sorry if it is. I know that the other side is true: if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_d),$ then $U:= Z/||Z|| \sim \mathcal{U}nif(S^{d-1}).$

Comment: Also for a general unit vector $v, U^{T}v$ seems hard to relate with $Ue_1, e_1:=(1, 0, \dots 0).$ I was thinking of using  rotation matrix to bring $v$ to $e_1, $ but couldn't make it work instantly. So I guess one way to go about it will be $ U^{T}v = v_1U_1 + \dots v_dU_d, U_i$ following square root of a  $Beta(1/2, \frac{d-1}{2})$ distribution as you showed. But these Beta distributions are not independent, being component of a sphere-valued distribution. So how do we calculate the distribution of $U^{T}v$ for a general unit vector $v?$

Comment: Your instinct is right: a rotation matrix does the trick.  I have edited my answer.  The details and consequence are easier than your comment implies.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer! One last question though (as mentioned in my comment above): how do we show that for any uniform distribution, there's a normal distribution $N$ with zero mean identify covariance matrix, so that the uniform distribution is the ration $N/||N||?$ You're using that argument in your answer, no?

Comment: I have edited again, with pointers to  $Z/\|Z\|$ being uniformly distributed on the sphere.  This is related to the spherical symmetry of both the sphere and of the multivariate  Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Thank you. But what I was pointing to was slightly different, and in fact the other direction of the statement. Yes, if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_d),$ then $\frac{Z}{||Z||}\sim Unif(S^{d-1}), ||Z|| \sim \chi_d.$ You mentioned this direction surely. But in order to finish the argument: we indeed need the other direction: $U \sim Unif(S^{d-1}) \implies \exists Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_d) $ so that $U= \frac{Z}{||Z||}.$ I'm not sure if it's in your argument? Do you've a source that proves it? I can ask a separate question and link it if you prefer. Thanks again!

Comment: P.S. I think one way to answer the question is to simply define $Z$ by: $Z:= U. \chi_d, \chi_d$ being a chi-distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom. It still remains to prove that $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_d),$ but I believe it's proven somewhere, although I don't know where. What do you think?

Comment: I think you are asking for a proof of Maxwell's theorem; my argument needs only its (easier) converse.  I think you should submit a separate question.  I'm having a hard time distinguishing in this comment thread exactly what you are saying.

Comment: I submitted a separate question here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767725/is-a-uniform-distribution-on-a-sphere-always-a-norm-scaled-normal-mathcaln0. However, I'm not after the proof of Maxwell's theorem, my point is that you started with the assumption that any uniform distribution $U$ arises as the norm scaled $N(0,I_d)$ distribution, which requires a proof.